# Parse not saving field

Tags: ios, swift, object, parse-platform

I am trying to save an object to Parse, and for some reason one field refuses to save. Everything else saves just fine. But not this one piece.

```
self.employeeObject.firstName = self.firstName.text!
            self.employeeObject.lastName = self.lastName.text!
            self.employeeObject.messages = self.messagesEnabledSwitch.on
            self.employeeObject.active = true
            self.employeeObject.pinNumber = "\(pinText!.text!)"
            print(self.employeeObject)
            do {
                try self.employeeObject.save()
            } catch {

            }
```

That prints out:

```
<Employees: 0x1265cc070, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {
active = 1;
firstName = m;
lastName = d;
messages = 0;
pin = 3434;
}
```

But when it saves, it doesnt save the pin number. The pin number is set as a string in parse. So i tried to make sure that the pin number it was giving was treated as such. By String(PIN) and "(Pin)" neither of which fixed my issue.

I checked my model, its correct. i use it for a number of other parts of the app as well just not this creation.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
Here is the Employee model that the employeeObject is from:

import Foundation
import Parse

```
class Employee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}

class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Employees"
}

var objectID : String {
    get {return objectForKey("objectId") as! String}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "objectId") }
}

var pinNumber : String? {
    get {return objectForKey("pinNumber") as? String}
    set { setObject(newValue!, forKey: "pin") }
}

var firstName : String {
    get {return objectForKey("firstName") as! String}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "firstName") }
}

var lastName : String {
    get {return objectForKey("lastName") as! String}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "lastName") }
}

var messages : Bool {
    get {return objectForKey("messages") as! Bool}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "messages") }
}

var userPoint : PFUser? {
    get {return objectForKey("userPointer") as? PFUser}
    set { setObject(newValue!, forKey: "userPointer") }
}

var roleType : Role? {
    get {return objectForKey("roleType") as? Role}
    set {setObject(newValue!, forKey: "roleType") }
}

var active : Bool {
    get { return objectForKey("active") as! Bool }
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "active") }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't develop new apps in Parse. That service is shutting down

Comment: @CodeDifferent - Yes Parse.com is shutting down but parse server is now open source and available for anyone to use.

Comment: Can you show us the Employee class. Also it looks like the Employees class has `pin` as a property while you are using `pinNumber`.

Comment: @Santhosh Added! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
var pinNumber : String? {
    get {return objectForKey("pinNumber") as? String}
    set { setObject(newValue!, forKey: "pin") }
}
```

Because you're setting `pin` but getting `pinNumber` so you will always get a default value because it's never been set.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I missed that.